# How to put liquid code inside a php string

Tags: php, codeigniter, liquid, shopify-app

I want to put Liquid code in a metafield with value type string. This is the Liquid code:

```
{% unless shop.metafields.cmld == blank %}
{%- assign cmld = shop.metafields.cmld -%}
 <div class="slider">
   {%- for field in cmld -%}
        <div>
            <img src="{{ field | last }}" />
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endunless %}
```

The Liquid code works fine when I try it on shopify. 
The problem here is this error on the 1st row:

```
{%'(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in .....
```

Any suggestions? It looks like this:

```
$add_metafield= array(
    "metafield" => array(
        "namespace"=> $metafield_namespace,
        "key"=> "something",
        "value" => "{% unless shop.metafields.".$metafield_namespace." == blank %}{%- assign ".$metafield_namespace." = shop.metafields.".$metafield_namespace." -%}<div class="slider">{%- for field in ".$metafield_namespace." -%}<div><img src="{{ field | last }}" /></div>{% endfor %}</div>{% endunless %}",
        "value_type" => "string"
    )
);
```

Comment: Your liquid code contains double quotes, so you either need to escape those - or use single quotes as the string delimiter.

Comment: use ' or " bring the same result

Comment: No it doesn’t, not if you do it correctly. Edit your question and show which code you tried now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0):

Change from double to single quotes in `<div class="slider">` and `<img src="{{ field | last }}" />`

changing it to -> `<div class='slider'>` and `<img src='{{ field | last }}' />`